# JQuery .hide...not hiding

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is probably a simple one but I can't seem to get it to work.

I have the following code:

```
<ul>
    <li class='jSH'>Users: <span>0</span></li>
    <li class='jSH'>Cars: <span>1</span></li>
</ul>
```

Essentially, I am trying to write a function that hides the li if the contents of span == 0.  This is the jquery code but it doesn't work for some reason:

```
if ($('.jSH span').text() == "0")
    $(this).closest('li').hide();
    alert("should hide");
```

So, in this case, I get one alert for the first li (because the contents of span == 0), but the li does not hide.

Is there a problem with using 'this' in this case?

Thanks!

Comment: What exactly do you think `this` is in javascript? ;) Your alert will also always fire because you aren't including `{` and `}` around the body of your if statement, which is bad practice

Comment: Where is your Javascript snippet from? Is it in a jQuery event handler (eg. click), a function or somewhere else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would want to use `.each` since your current code returns multiple objects and their contents - `.each` will seperate them into a loop-like process where each individual element  will be processed. 
Fiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/fEEFq/
Javascript Code:

```
    $('.jSH span').each(function(){
        if ($(this).text() == "0"){
            $(this).closest('li').hide();
            alert("should hide"); 
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is in `$(this)` - this, in the context of jQuery, only works when within a event callback (for example mouseover or click). You should fix that line to:

```
$('.jSH span').closest('li').hide();
```

Furthermore, you don't have `{}` around the body of the if statement. This will cause only the first statement after the if to be executed.

Answer (score 2):

You can use $.filter

```
$('.jSH').filter(function() {
  return $('span',this).text() == "0";
}).hide();
```

Answer (score 1):

You're referring `this` to a conditional statement, which will not return your desired results.

Instead:

```
$('.jSH span').each(function(){
    if ($(this).text() == "0"){  // now `this` is referring to every span in the jQuery collection
        $(this).closest('li').hide();
    }
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/each/

Comment: Perfect - will JQuery throw an error if there are no .jSH classes on the page?

Comment: @Angelo, no. It will not. Will just simply ignore if no elements are returned in the collection.